# Post deleted after giving a good (edited) answer

Tags: support, deleted-answers, moderation, community-moderation

I made a post to give an answer about a topic I was working on lately.

[Adventures in Installing a C#/WPF Application (WiX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305272/adventures-in-installing-a-c-wpf-application-wix/69737454#69737454)

I made a vague answer and started editing it right away after posting realizing that it looked extremely bad without any other info.

When I posted the edit I saw a comment demanding exactly that, so I didn't take any further action, just stated so on a comment

> Just started edit right after posting. TY.

Planning to delete it when commenter's downvote would disappear.

2 minutes after, the answer was deleted by a different moderator than the comment one, without any further information.

The deletion by a moderator locks the post status and no further action can be done by myself on the post.

I edited my last comment  to state the misunderstanding but I assume such edits would not be noticed to the moderator:

> Just started edit right after posting. TY. Was deleting really necessary? It answers exactly what the OP was asking on the last phrase

Furthermore I edited the answer to add a message to the edit hoping the moderator would read it:

> I edited the post 2 minutes after posting. May the moderator not see the edit and delete it right away?

---

Even thought, the initial answer provides an easy to use path for exactly what OP was asking for:

> All I want is a simple installer that copies over the EXE and associated DLLs. Why is this so difficult? Can WiX do what I need? Or do I need a different installer toolkit?

The edit made amends what another user asked for on the comment even before I read it as I saw the issue as soon as I posted the answer.

I can imagine 2 possible causes for the deletion after the edit:

- The edit didn't reach the moderator, who locked the answer with the old content.
- The moderator saw the final post result and found it wasn't providing a good answer based solely on the recent comment which was referencing the old content.

In my opinion, both cases fall out of what it's [generally expected from moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators):

- Are patient and fair
- Lead by example
- Show respect for their fellow community members in their actions and words

Awaiting, at least for few minutes, would be a great opportunity to provide a leady by example about how this community has been built to be moderated through the interaction of its own users. Being patient and ultimately giving a fair comment (words) stating that the answer have not been fixed in an acceptable amount of time would have been a great input for any other moderator viewing such action.

I would like to request the post being undeleted.

Comment: Your answer was deleted by a moderator in response to a "Not an Answer" flag raised by the community. It is of the form that we typically describe as a "link-only answer". You can read more about "Not an Answer" flags in [the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer). **Moderators are not expected to *wait* for you post an answer that meets [our minimum requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). The time to compose an answer that meets our minimum requirements is *before* you click the "Submit" button, not after.**

Comment: While I agree with your last statement, the moderator didn't need to wait as the edit was made before the post deletion. Just wanted to give my view on how I though this situations to be modded acording to the "generally expected from moderators". I acknowledged the mistake and tried to amend it but the new valid answer was deleted anyways. I'm just asking for the post to be undeleted back, not for the moderator to be punished or anything like that.

Comment: To be fair, that answer is not that good even after the edit. The essential parts that actually answer the question are still behind the links.

Comment: And regardless, I do expect moderators to handle situations promptly. With so many situations of varying priorities emerging every day, it is counter productive to have them waiting for NAA answers to become proper answers (which might not even happen, as evidenced here).

Comment: Your post was initially flagged for being a link-only answer, which it was. You then edited it by expanding with more links, making it still a link-only answer. The answer reads as an endorsement of the links, which is completely worthless if the links die. If you want your post to be undeleted, [start by removing its dependencies on external links](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). You can also edit while the post is deleted, [as you've already figured out you can](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69737454/revisions), and you normally raise a mod flag when you've fixed your post

Comment: @Zoe Please do not use comments as answers. Answers belong in the space below.

Comment: As the answer below didn't really serve me, I gave a similar answer with what worked for me. The wait is just my expectation. The deletion happened after the delete. Everyday we see accepted answers with way less content than that. Furthermore, the OP was having issues with the research of finding a how to, this is not a HTML/CSS post, I would not expect an entire WIX project to be posted as an answer on most of cases. I understand your position and won't push it anymore. Hope someone ends up looking for an answer and has the permissions to view the post he can take some profit.

Comment: You are right, @Dharman, but I think we can forgive the new mod who is busy learning the new tools. Appreciate you writing a good answer for her. :-)

Comment: There is no reason to think that the moderator saw anything other than your first edit even if by the time they hit delete you had edited further. Post good posts. Not bad posts. (But also your later edits did not change the post from being NAA.)

Answer (score 16):

I'm sorry, but your post was not an answer at all and deserved to be deleted right away. You had all the time before posting it, to work on it. We can't be expected to wait patiently for you to fix your answer after posting it. Sometimes, we might wait a few minutes or fix small mistakes ourselves if we think the post can be salvaged. You have been given a helpful comment explaining why your answer is not an answer. If you want you can post a **different** answer but that one looked unsalvagable. You can also edit the answer after it's deleted and request a moderator to undelete it, but you must turn it into an answer first.

#### Why is it not an answer?

It's not an answer because there is no solution to the problem in the post itself. The solution might be behind a link, but links are not considered a solution on Stack Overflow. Each solution must be self-contained within a single Stack Overflow post. There can be supportive links though.

Let's dissect your post while ignoring the links:

> This was the best input I found when trying to deal with WIX and installers:
>
> It served me very well and you have the source code available if you are not willing to write it while watching:

This is just your personal opinion and contains no solution.

> I did add more tweaks when I did it for first time but this is a great point to start with.

What tweaks? Are they important in solving the problem? Why haven't you explained these tweaks?

> Watching the video is really recommended. Otherwise, the most important thing that you may skip taking a look around is the .wixproj file, which is heavily edited. The most useful thing there is the *HeatDirectory* command.

Why should one look at that file? What is in that file? Why is `HeatDirectory` useful?

The problem here might also be that the question is too broad and cannot be answered with a single answer. In such a case, the question should be closed.

P.S. Comments such as "*Just started edit right after posting. TY."* are unnecessary. They waste time and are considered noise. If you are going to edit it, then do so. You can ping the comment after it's done if you think they might not have become aware of your edit, but many people follow the post when posting comments like this so they know when you fixed it. If not then another user will come along and mark the comment as no longer needed.